# How to overwrite a patch/commit instead of skipping it while rebasing

Tags: git, rebase

While rebasing a branch onto another (rebasing `dev` branch onto `master`) as below

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

if a conflict occurs, then we see the following options

```
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Now, to resolve the conflicts, we either manually edit the files or skip the patch (`git rebase --skip`) to eliminate the patch that is creating conflicts while rebasing.

But what i wanted here is to overwrite the patch from dev and ignore the patch which is in master already... something like (`git rebase --overwrite`)

Is there any such option or any other way to do it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by overwriting a commit instead of skipping it.  Either a commit is applied, in its entirety, or it is skipped.  In any case, you should be able to get the level of control you want at the file level.

When rebasing and encountering a conflict, there are *two* parents for each file in conflict.  If you had some file `path/to/file.ext` and you wanted to overwrite with the *master* version, then you could use:

```
git checkout --ours path/to/file.ext
git add path/to/file.ext
```

If you wanted to use the *dev* version of the same file, then you could use this:

```
git checkout --theirs path/to/file.ext
git add path/to/file.ext
```

This answer assumes the situation you described in your question, namely that you rebased `dev` on `master`, from the latter branch:

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

Comment: Yea this is what I am looking for. What I meant by overwritting a commit is nothing but `git checkout --theirs <filename>`. As `git checkout --ours <filename>` is similar to `git rebase --skip`

Comment: OK, but remember if you skip an entire patch, it means _every_ file, whereas my answer just tells you how to skip over a _single_ file.

Comment: Oh yeah! So to be more precise `git rebase --skip` is similar to `git checkout --ours .`